# WordPress - Code to display post of certain category and display a custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I've done hours of Google searching but still stumped on where to start.

I'm trying to display a grid of posts in a certain category, whilst also grabbing and displaying a custom field in that post.

I just need a starting point, then I can figure out how to implement it and then style it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try this code:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'medlem',
'tax_query' => array(
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'field' => 'term_id',
    'terms' => 4
)
)
);
```

As 'field' => 'term_id' is default you can skip this line. For more information go to: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

You can display a list of post in the grid by using category id in an array with a query like below:

```
 <?php global $post;
 $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => array(1,2,4) );
 foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
     $custom_field = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'your_key', true); // TO get custom field value of post.. ?>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>  
<?php endforeach;
 wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

You can also get custom field value by using `get_post_meta` function with post id like mentioned above code.

Hope this will helpful for you. Thanks.